# Lasagne 1D Convolution Error

Tags: python, neural-network, conv-neural-network, lasagne

I am trying to build a CNN using Lasagne and I have 119 feature variables.  I am able to successfully build a MLP using Lasagne but when I try to add a Convolutional layer (using 1D convolution) using the following code, I get an error.  Am I doing something wrong?  Has the 1D convolution in Lasagne been tested?

```
def build_custom_mlp(input_var, depth, width):
    network = lasagne.layers.InputLayer(shape=(None, 119), input_var=input_var)
    network = lasagne.layers.Conv1DLayer(network, num_filters=20, filter_size=10,
              stride=1, pad=1, nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify)
    network = lasagne.layers.Pool1DLayer(network, pool_size=2)
    nonlin = lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify
    network = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(network, width, nonlinearity=nonlin)
    # Output layer:
    relu = lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify
    network = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(network, 60, nonlinearity=relu)
    return network
```

> File "/Users/adityanagarajan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lasagne/layers/dense.py", line 63, in __init__
>       super(DenseLayer, self).__init__(incoming, **kwargs)
>     File "/Users/adityanagarajan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lasagne/layers/base.py", line 35, in __init__
>       self.input_shape = incoming.output_shape
>     File "/Users/adityanagarajan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lasagne/layers/base.py", line 49, in output_shape
>       return self.get_output_shape_for(self.input_shape)
>     File "/Users/adityanagarajan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lasagne/layers/conv.py", line 237, in get_output_shape_for
>       output_length = conv_output_length(input_shape[2],
>   IndexError: tuple index out of range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you the answer:

> line 237, in get_output_shape_for output_length = conv_output_length(input_shape[2], IndexError: tuple index out of range

If you check the [source](https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/blob/master/lasagne/layers/conv.py), on line 237, a tuple is trying to be indexed that doesn't have 3 elements in it.  If you reshape your data it should resolve the error, try `(None, 1, 119)` as your input.

Comment: Yeah I tried that but my `input_var` is a Theano tensor `input_var = T.dmatrix('inputs') `, so I get an error when I use `(None,1,119)`, `ValueError: shape has 3 dimensions, but variable has 2`. I am wondering why the tuple must have a length of 3(`input_shape[2]`) for a 1D convolution.

Comment: Ya you need to change your input_var to `T.tensor3()`.  Theano doesn't have a 1D convolution.  The guys at Lasagne wrote extensions to "fake" them.  The default conv function for `Conv1DLayer()` is `conv1d_mc0()`; you can see its implementation [here](https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/blob/master/lasagne/theano_extensions/conv.py).  A 2D-conv has a 4D input: (batch_size, channel, height, width). So a 1D-conv has input (batch_size, channel, length).  You are inputing (batch_size, length) which is a 0D-conv (which is not even a thing and doesn't make sense).

Comment: Thank you! used the T.tensor3() and reshaped to (num_examples,1,119) and works fine.